# 'File not found' using username.bitbucket.io?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Trying to publish a static page using bitbucket pages. I have followed instructions in this article to the letter but still can't seem to get it working and there has not been much help from atlassian community.
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/publishing-a-website-on-bitbucket-cloud-221449776.html?_ga=2.113777344.635815864.1537122684-1179533745.1536933925

I signed up with username 'justtryingthisout'. Then created a repository with the name "justtryingthisout.bitbucket.io"

package.json
`{
  "name": "test_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "test application",
  "homepage": "https://justtryingthisout.bitbucket.io",`

I created my app using `npm i create-react-app`. Also got config using `npm eject`. Below is my project structure. Here in "manifest.json" which contains my root index.html, I have tried to use start url in different ways to make it work as `"start_url": "./index.html"` OR `"start_url": "/index.html"` OR `"start_url": ".index.html"`. Nothing seems to work

If anyone had similar issue or got any suggestions on what I can try would be helpful. Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

UPDATE:
After moving index.html in the root of project structure I see only the text from the html file but no react code as referenced from the " id = 'root' ". My index.js renders in DOM using the id=root from index.html like so `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`. I get absolutely no errors or logs in console.
[image]

Below is expanded project structure.
Is bitbucket looking for a particular project structure or any other specifics other that index.html present in root folder??
[image]

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The [BitBucket page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/publishing-a-website-on-bitbucket-cloud-221449776.html?_ga=2.113777344.635815864.1537122684-1179533745.1536933925) does mention

> Create an `index.html` file in the repository **root**.

As long as your `index.html` is not in the root folder of your Git repository, it won't be accessible by `https://justtryingthisout.bitbucket.io`

Comment: VonC thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my question accordingly but issue is not resolved yet. Please let me know if I can try anything else. thanks

Comment: @codenoob Not sure (I did answer your initial question though). A Bitbucket page is just a static web server: it does not expect a particular structure: just an index file and its files the index.html code reference.